# Introducir varios links con Jade

Tags: nodejs, express, jade

Buenos días,

Me gustaría saber como puedo poner varios "links" con Jade, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
doctype html
html(lang="es")
    head
        title Powergraph
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="estatico/app.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="estatico/form-elements.css" rel="stylesheet")    
    body
        block index
```

El error que me dice es:

> Error: C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\views\layout.jade:9
>
> 7|      link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
>   rel="stylesheet")
>
> 8|         link(href="estatico/app.css" rel="stylesheet")
>
> > 9|       link(href="estatico/form-elements.css" rel="stylesheet")
>
> 10|    body
>
> 11|        block index
>
> unexpected text       bo
>       at Object.fail (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:887:11)
>       at Object.next (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:947:15)
>       at Object.lookahead (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:113:46)
>       at Parser.lookahead (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:102:23)
>       at Parser.peek (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:79:17)
>       at Parser.tag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:773:22)
>       at Parser.parseTag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:759:17)
>       at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:211:21)
>       at Parser.block (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:729:25)
>       at Parser.tag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:838:24)
>       at Parser.parseTag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:759:17)
>       at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:211:21)
>       at Parser.block (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:729:25)
>       at Parser.tag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:838:24)
>       at Parser.parseTag (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:759:17)
>       at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\Manux\Desktop\cursoNodeJS\proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:211:21)

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como tienes index.jade

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado poniendo la final del ultimo "link" un "/"

```
doctype html
html(lang="es")
    head
        title Powergraph
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="estatico/app.css" rel="stylesheet")
        link(href="estatico/form-elements.css" rel="stylesheet")/   
    body
        block index
```